# problem with my store cart using react and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have a store website that using react, nodejs and postgresql

The connection of java Script with the data structure was successful and I manage to import the products that are in the table and they appear in the store on the website, but when I click the add to cart button it does not add them and shows me a nan value in the nav bar.

store.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { ShopContext } from "./Shop-Context";
import StoreFilter from "./StoreFilter";
import { Product } from "./Product";
import "./Store.css";

const Store = () => {
  const [filterTextvalue, updateFilterText] = useState("all");
  const { products } = useContext(ShopContext); 

  let filteredProductList = products.filter((product) => {
    if (filterTextvalue === "Gaming Mouses") {
      return product.type === "Mouse";
    } else if (filterTextvalue === "Gaming Keyboards") {
      return product.type === "Keyboard";
    } else if (filterTextvalue === "Gaming Headphones") {
      return product.type === "Headphones";
    } else if (filterTextvalue === "Gaming pads") {
      return product.type === "Gamepad";
    } else if (filterTextvalue === "Gaming Controllers") {
      return product.type === "GameController";
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });

  function onFilterValueSelected(FilterValue) {
    updateFilterText(FilterValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="shop">
      <div className="shopTitle">
        <h1>Gaming World Shop</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="StoreFilter">
        <StoreFilter onFilterValueSelected={onFilterValueSelected}></StoreFilter>
      </div>

      <div className="products">
        {filteredProductList.map((product) => (
          <Product data={product} key={product.product_id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

product.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ShopContext } from "./Shop-Context";

export const Product = (props) => {
  const { product_id, name, price, image_path } = props.data;
  const { addToCart, cartItems } = useContext(ShopContext);

  const cartItemCount = cartItems[product_id];


  return (
    <div className="product">
      <img src={require(`${image_path}`)} alt={"img"} />
      <div className="description">
        <p>
          <b>{name}</b>
        </p>
        <p>{price}</p>
      </div>
      <button className="addToCartBttn" onClick={() => addToCart(product_id)}>
        Add To Cart {cartItemCount > 0 && <> ({cartItemCount})</>}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

cart.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ShopContext } from "./Shop-Context";
import { CartItem } from "./Cart_item";
import "./Cart.css";

export const Cart = () => {
  const { cartItems, getTotalCartAmount, resetCart } = useContext(ShopContext);
  const totalAmount = getTotalCartAmount();
  const { products } = useContext(ShopContext); 
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleContinuePurchase = () => {
    navigate("/Payment", { state: { totalAmount: totalAmount } });
  };

  return (
    <div className="cart">
      <div>
        <h1>Your Cart Items</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="cart">
        {products.map((product) => {
          if (cartItems[product.product_id] !== 0) {
              return <CartItem data={product} key={product.product_id} />;
          }
          return null; // Default return value when the condition is not met
        })}
      </div>

      {totalAmount > 0 ? (
        <>
          <div className="checkout">
            <p> Subtotal: ₪{totalAmount} </p>
            <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}> Continue Shopping </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                resetCart();
                navigate("/Cart");
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              Reset Cart{" "}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="purchase">
            <button onClick={handleContinuePurchase}>Continue purchase</button>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <h1> Your Shopping Cart is Empty</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

cart_item.jsx

```
import React, { useContext} from "react";
import { ShopContext } from "./Shop-Context";

export const CartItem = (props) => {
  const { product_id, name, price, image_path } = props.data;
  const { cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, updateCartItemCount } = useContext(ShopContext);

  return (
    <div className="cartItem">
      <img src={require(`${image_path}`)} alt={"img"} />
      <div className="description">
        <p>
          <b>{name}</b>
        </p>
        <p> Price:{price}</p>
        <div className="countHandler">
          <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product_id)}> - </button>
          <input
            value={cartItems[product_id]}
            onChange={(e) => updateCartItemCount(Number(e.target.value), product_id)}
          />
          <button onClick={() => addToCart(product_id)}> + </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

shop-context.jsx

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const ShopContext = createContext(null);

export const ShopContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  // Define getDefaultCart using products after it's initialized
  const getDefaultCart = () => {
    let cart = {};
    for (let i = 1; i < products.length + 1; i++) {
      cart[i] = 0;
    }
    return cart;
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch product data when the component mounts
    fetch("/api/products")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Fetched products:", data);
        // Update the products state with the fetched data
        setProducts(data);
         // Initialize the cart with the fetched products
        setCartItems(getDefaultCart());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching products:", error);
      });
  },[]);

  const getTotalCartAmount = () => {
    let totalAmount = 0;
    for (const item in cartItems) {
      if (cartItems[item] > 0) {
        let itemInfo = products.find((product) => product.product_id === Number(item));
        totalAmount += cartItems[item] * itemInfo.price;
      }
    }
    return totalAmount;
  };

  const getTotalCartItemsCount = () => {
    let CartAmount = 0;
    for (const item in cartItems) {
      CartAmount += cartItems[item];
    }
    return CartAmount;
  };

  const addToCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] + 1 }));
  };

  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] - 1 }));
  };

  const updateCartItemCount = (newAmount, itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: newAmount }));
  };

  const resetCart = () => {
    setCartItems(getDefaultCart());
  };

  const payMent = () => {
    setCartItems(getTotalCartAmount());
  };

  const contextValue = {
    cartItems,
    addToCart,
    updateCartItemCount,
    removeFromCart,
    getTotalCartAmount,
    getTotalCartItemsCount,
    resetCart,
    payMent,
    products,
  };

  return (
    <ShopContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </ShopContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

the products table and the data

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price MONEY NOT NULL CHECK (price > '0'::MONEY),
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    image_path TEXT
);

INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, type, image_path)
VALUES
  (1, 'Hyperx Cloud 2 red Gaming Headset', 300.0, 'Headphones', './products/product1.jpg'),
  (2, 'Logitech G332 Gaming Headset', 200.0, 'Headphones', './products/product2.jpg'),
  (3, 'Logitech G502 Proteus Spectrum', 329.0, 'Mouse', './products/product3.jpg'),
  (4, 'Logitech G Pro Wireless', 354.0, 'Mouse', './products/product4.png'),
  (5, 'Razer Firefly Hard V2 RGB Gaming Mouse Pad', 39.99, 'Gamepad', './products/product5.jpg'),
  (6, 'XBox Elite Series 2', 399.0, 'GameController', './products/product6.jpeg'),
  (7, 'SteelSeries Apex 7 Red Switch', 350.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product7.jpg'),
  (8, 'Logitech G513 Mechanical Gaming Keyboard', 530.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product8.jpg'),
  (9, 'Logitech G903 Lightspeed Hero', 294.0, 'Mouse', './products/product9.jpg'),
  (10, 'Lenovo Legion M600 RGB', 170.0, 'Mouse', './products/product10.jpg'),
  (11, 'Corsair M65 RGB ULTRA WIRELES Tunable FPS', 470.0, 'Mouse', './products/product11.jpg'),
  (12, 'Logitech G603 Lightspeed WIRELES Mouse', 230.0, 'Mouse', './products/product12.jpg'),
  (13, 'Corsair K55 RGB PRO', 174.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product13.jpg'),
  (14, 'Corsair K70 RGB TKL CHAMPION with OPX SWITCHES', 470.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product14.jpg'),
  (15, 'Dragon RGB GPDRA-K18', 119.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product15.jpg'),
  (16, 'Logitech G Pro Tenkeyless GX Blue Switch', 670.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product16.jpg'),
  (17, 'Roccat Magma Membrane Gaming Keyboard RGB', 210.0, 'Keyboard', './products/product17.jpg'),
  (18, 'SteelSeries rival 650 Gaming Mouse', 423.0, 'Mouse', './products/product18.png'),
  (19, 'SteelSeries Arctis Pro Gaming Headset', 730.0, 'Headphones', './products/product19.jpg'),
  (20, 'Corsair MM350 Champion Series Mouse - Medium Pad', 81.0, 'Gamepad', './products/product20.jpg')
```

[this is my store as you can see when i click on add to cart i get nan value in the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c7NL.png) 
[this is my cart, as you can see all the products are moved to the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHQ0T.png)

i try to fix the functions in the shop context, and try to use Chatgpt also, And it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure why `cartItems` is an object. Try using an array instead of an object for your cart items. Store product_id in array when you add a product to cart. That should make it easier.
Add to cart function would just do this: `setCartItems(prev => [...prev, itemId])`

Comment: im getting an error when im doing this: prev is not iterable
TypeError: prev is not iterable

Comment: You have to define the state like this: `const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);`